# Testing Captcha in php

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

I'm hoping of having this captcha on my website:

http://lirullu.com/

how would i test the outcome of this in a php form? Here is the code I have in my form.php file currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function() {

                var righthash1 = "cc03412089f87b9c509aaaa1";

                $("#hf023d03").sortable({
                  items: ".cnt", stop: function () {
                    hash = "";
                    $("#hf023d03 .cnt").each(function (a, b) { hash += $(b).attr("id"); }); if (hash == righthash1) {
                        $(".slg1").fadeIn("fast");
                    } else {
                        $(".slg1").fadeOut("fast");
                    }
                  }
                });

            });

            </script>

            <div id="first_cnt">
                    <h2>Are you a traveline hero?</h2>
                    <span class="htext">(drag the answer)</span>
                    <div class="d1" id="hf023d03">
                        <div class="cnt" id="509aaaa1"><span class="yes">S</span></div>
                        <div class="cnt" id="89f87b9c"><span class="yes">E</span></div>
                        <div class="cnt" id="cc034120"><span class="yes">Y</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slg1">
                        <h3>is the correct answer!</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider using Google's reCaptcha which has possibly the nicest API.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha

You can follow the tutorials and guides, it provides you the PHP and the Javascript you need to integrate the system with any website you create.

Comment: I really would like to use the above example though.